# incomplete type 'void' is not assignable c

Tags: c, pointers

I am experiencing an error for the following double pointer to void variable, `void ** foo`. I do not understand why I get this error although I am casting the struct type. Shouldn't `*heap->foo[0]` now contain/point to the address of `personA`?

```
typedef struct Person{
    char * name;
    char age;
}Person;

typedef struct myStruct{
    void ** foo;
}myStruct;

void initialize(myStruct * H, int numbOfPersons){
     H->foo = malloc(sizeof(myStruct*));
    *H->foo = malloc(sizeof(myStruct)*numberOfPersons);

 }

void insert(myStruct * H, void * personA){
    *H->foo[0] = (myStruct)personA;  //error here
}

int main(void){
    myStruct heap;
    int numberOfPpl = 2;
    initialize(heap, numberOfPpl);

    Person A;
    A.grade = 10
    strcpy(A->name, "Jason");

    Insert(&heap, &A); 
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
incomplete type 'void' is not assignable
                 *H->foo[0] = (Student*)I;
```

Comment: Is it `struct` a valid name for a variable????....

Comment: The error you describe does not appear in your code. Please show the code that causes your error.

Comment: @Casa: look like you typed the code here again. You can do copy-paste instead. `typedef struct{....}mystruct;` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `void` is not assignable! The left side of an assignment must have an assignable type. You need to cast the left side of the assignment. The tricky part is that you need to do the cast at the pointer level:

```
*(myStruct*)H->foo[0] = *personA;
```

There are also some other bugs in your code. Turn up the warning level in your compiler so you can see them (`-Wall` if you use gcc).

Answer (score 1):

there are some errors in your code:
wrong function:

```
void initialize(myStruct * H, int numbOfPersons){
     H->foo = malloc(sizeof(Person*)); // as I understand you want to add person in H with type of myStruct
    *H->foo = malloc(sizeof(Person)*numbOfPersons);
 }
```

- you have allocated memory for your variable with type myStruct but you don't use it and you loose you allocation if you make `H->foo[0] = something` you should use memcpy
- if you use H->foo[0] don't add `*` H->foo[0] = *H->foo

`void insert(myStruct * H, void * personA){
    memcpy(H->foo[0], (void*)personA, sizeof(struct Person));  //error here
}`

`myStruct struct1;` don't use C keywords as a variable name

```
Person A;
A.age = 10; // grade does not exist in your struct and you have forget ;
strcpy(A.name, "Jason"); // A is not a pointer don't use A->name and also you must allocate the memory before do strcpy or use char name[number_of_char] definition
```

Don't forget to free allocated memory if you use memory dynamic allocation

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I have updated my response